# PL/SQL how to compare dates in proc

Tags: plsql, compare, date

Dates in my DB are stored like this: "2/6/2009 6:30:00 PM". What is the proper way to compare this date to a date I'm passing in from my UI in a stored procedure?

Trying to do something like
TE_ES_ACT_END_DATETIME < '2/6/2009 07:30:00', 
but this isn't working. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the TO_DATE function to translate a text to a date.

Like so:

```
to_date('2/6/2009 6:30:00 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM')
```

If you use the field name instead of the constant string, you will get the field value, translated to a date. You can compare it in your query, or return it and compare it in PL/SQL code using the normal > or < operators.

But of course, it is better to save the date as a date. :) If you like, you can do a step by step conversion:

First, add a date column to the table and write a trigger that
   updates the stringdate field whenever a date is entered.

```
  create or replace trigger DATESYNC before insert or update of YOURNEWDATEFIELD
  on YOURTABLE for each row
  begin
    :new.CURRENTSTRINGDATE := to_char(:new.YOURNEWDATEFIELD, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM');
  end;
```

Then, edit the GUI that you use to enter a date in the date field
   instead of the string field. All other code will still make use of
   the string field and will keep working.
Write an update statement that uses `to_data` to convert each text to a date.

Then, you can one by one eliminate all code that reads the string
   field and update it to use the date field. All code that is not converted yet will still work, because the trigger still updates the string field.

After all code is converted, drop the string field and the trigger.

That will make your code faster, your data more compact, and your queries will make better use of indexes on the date field.